# ec2 instance is getting down through nagios server

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

ec2 instance is getting down while monitoring via nagios server and another digitalocean droplet being monitor via same nagios server while port 5666 TCP port enable on ec2 instance.

I followed this documentation for set up Nagios Server & client
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nagios-4-and-monitor-your-servers-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Nagios server does is an ICMP request to the client a.k.a ( ping ) to check the client healthy. With that said, we need to allow the ICMP (in security group add: All ICMP - IPv4 with source anywhere) protocol on your instance, by doing that i abled to check the client health and check the instance status.